# Running java script at another place of site

Tags: javascript

I searched through internet and this site as well but haven't found the answer. I would like to run a javascript code, which will go through articles at my site and choose&print some of them. The script works well when I run it after this articles:

[articles about smartphones]

[script which displays (prints) some of the articles about smartphones]

Obviously, it works correctly because script have what to search through - articles have already appeared at site, so javascript can take some elements.

But I want to invert the order:

[display some of the articles about smartphones there]

[show articles about smartphones there]

I assume that I should run the script after the articles loaded and than change the position of element, which was printed by script. I can do that with position: absolute; but it doesn't look too elegant for me and I hope that there is another way to solve my problem. I tried body onload and running function at another place, but I haven't do the trick.

Thank you for any help and suggestions : )

Comment: If you are open to using jQuery, having your script in $(document).ready(function() { /* your script */ }); will most probably do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are using document.write to generate the HTML code to redisplay some of the articles. *You should not use document.write*. Instead, put the script at very end of your document, to make sure all HTML elememts are already present in the DOM. Then create a new HTMLNode, eg a div, and put it where you want it or select one from the DOM and put your new HTML into that node (the simplest way is to set `innerHTML`). Eg:

```
<body>
  <div id="some_articles">
  </div>
  <div id="all_articles">
    <!--- here is the code for all articles -->
  </div>
  <script>
    var div = document.getElementById('some_articles');
    div.innerHTML = '<!-- code for some of the articles -->';
  </script>
</body>
```

This is very basic Javascript knowledge however. You should really read a good tutorial or a book on Javascript and DOM programming.

Comment: Thank you very much for advice - it worked for me! I'm just starting learning javascript and document.write was the one I've already learned so I tried to use. I'll dig into js more and of course I'll start to learn from better, more advanced sources. : )

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you are trying to do with your script.  A script cannot reference DOM elements that are loaded after the script.  So, if that's what you're trying to do, then your script must be placed after those DOM elements have been loaded or it must wait until those elements are loaded before executing.

If you're just trying to reorder existing DOM elements, then you can use `removeChild` and `appendChild` or `insertBefore` to reposition DOM elements in the page layout flow to change ordering.

If you want the viewer to not see the original order, then you can set up an initial CSS rule so the articles are initially not visible and then you can reorder them and make them visible.  The viewer will only see the final order.

If you want more specific advice, I'd suggest you your actual code so we can see it is actually doing so we can advise more specifically.

Comment: Thank you for interest, these are some great tips and I hope I'll have a chance to use them : ) Sorry, maybe I should've wrote more clearly, but now I have my problem solved with help from Daniel Baulig.